# LinkedHashSet to implement LRU

Tags: java, hashmap, lru

I want to remove the oldest member of a `LinkedHashSet` , I know that there's a `removeEldestEntry` method that I have to override ([Java doc for removeEldestEntry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry%28java.util.Map.Entry%29)
),
but I guess that I have to define `initial capacity` and `load factor` which I don't care and I simply want to remove the element which was least recently accessed (here by access I mean being `put` while it's already in the set or being read)

Is there any way not to override `removeEldestEntry` ?

Answer (score 32):

> I know that there's a removeEldestEntry method that I have to **override**

**This statement is wrong since `LinkedHashSet` HAS-A `LinkedHashMap` and not IS-A.**

You could use the useful (although not well known), [Collections.newSetFromMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap%28java.util.Map%29) method:

```
Set<String> mySet = Collections.newSetFromMap(new LinkedHashMap<String, Boolean>(){
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<String, Boolean> eldest) {
        return size() > MAX_ENTRIES;
    }
});
```

It will thus return a `Set` vision of a `LinkedHashMap` (a Set-Like interface) implementing your custom `removeEldestEntry` method.

`MAX_ENTRIES` being a custom constant that you would have defined.

Comment: That's brilliant!

Now with Java 13 and up, is there any other way to create a LRU set?

Answer (score 0):

Slight enhancement to the above answer:

```
    Collections.newSetFromMap(new LinkedHashMap<T, Boolean>(maxSize, 0.75f, true) {  

      @Override
      public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
       // Unfortunately, the LinkedHashMap containsKey method doesn't reset the LRU order, 
       // so perform a 'get' call here too
        return super.containsKey(key)
                && super.get(key); 
      }

      @Override
      protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<T, Boolean> eldest) {
        return this.size() > maxSize;
      }
    });
```